# How do I extract lowercase vowels/consonants in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, extract

When I insert the string "Character Extractor" my output on Extract Vowels is "Chrctr Extrctr", and for Consonant Extractor the output is "Caae Eao". I thought I converted my string from the user input into lower but as you can see the upper case letters are not being checked.

Intended output for each would be "Chrctr xtrctr" and "aae Eao". How do I change this up for my intended results?

Bonus: How would I do this with regex instead?

```
import tkinter as tk
import re

class CharacterExtractor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mainWindow = tk.Tk()
        self.characterLabel = tk.Label(self.mainWindow, text = "Character Extracter")
        self.characterEntry = tk.Entry(self.mainWindow)
        self.vowelButton = tk.Button(self.mainWindow, text = "Extract Vowels", command = self.getVowels)
        self.consonantButton = tk.Button(self.mainWindow, text = "Extract Consonants", command = self.getConsonants)
        self.lettersValue = tk.StringVar()
        self.lettersValue.set("-")
        self.outputLabel = tk.Label(self.mainWindow, textvariable = self.lettersValue)
        self.characterLabel.pack()
        self.characterEntry.pack()
        self.vowelButton.pack()
        self.consonantButton.pack()
        self.outputLabel.pack()
        tk.mainloop()

    def getVowels(self):
        letters = str(self.characterEntry.get())
        vowels = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
        for x in letters.lower():
            if x in vowels:
                letters = letters.replace(x, "")
                self.lettersValue.set(letters)

    def getConsonants(self):
        letters = str(self.characterEntry.get())
        vowels = ("b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z")
        for x in letters.lower():
            if x in vowels:
                letters = letters.replace(x, "")
                self.lettersValue.set(letters)     

mainWindow = CharacterExtractor()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In the `getVowels` and `getConstants` functions, you are iterating over the string letters.lower() but when trying to remove/replace `letters.replace(x, "")` , you are trying to delete the lowercase letter which is not present in letters.

Simple fix :  `letters.replace(x.lower(), "")`

Based on the replacements being done, I would suggest to use the re module to do all replacements together rather than in a loop - `re.sub("[aeiou]", "", letters, 0, re.I)`

Answer (score 0):

A slightly easier method to get vowels and consonants could be:

```
from string import ascii_letters  # A to Z and a to z

vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
consonants = ''.join(set(ascii_letters)-set(vowels))
```

EDIT: Following the regex example given by [Prashanth Mariswamy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62983967/python-vowel-extractor-lower/62984247#62984247):

To delete vowels (using the vowels above):

```
re.sub(f"[{vowels}]", "", letters)
```

To delete consonants (using consonants above):

```
re.sub(f"[{consonants}]", "", letters)
```